# Cursor Issue in CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am a building a website in just HTML & CSS and have run into an issue. I am trying to apply `cursor:pointer` on the button in the hero section. When I hover over the button, the cursor doesn't point over the button as it should.
[image]

```css
#hero-section {
  background: url('../images/Hero\ section.jpg') center center/cover;
  height: 90vh;
  position: relative;
  z-index: -2;
}

#overlay {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  background: #000;
  opacity: 45%;
  z-index: -1;
}

.break {
  display: block;
}

.hero-content {
  padding-top: 18vh;
  text-align: center;
}

.hero-title {
  font-size: 60px;
  font-family: 'Playfair Display', sans-serif;
  color: #fff;
  margin-bottom: 2rem;
}

.btn-primary {
  background: #A841A1;
  color: #fff;
  border: none;
  padding: 1.25rem;
  font-size: 16px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<!-- Hero section -->
<section id="hero-section">
  <div id="overlay"></div>
  <div class="hero-content">
    <h1 class="hero-title">Experience The Best Beauty <span class="break">Services</span></h1>
    <button class="btn-primary">BOOK YOUR TREATMENT</button>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Why do you have `z-index: -2;` on `#hero-section`?

Answer (score 1):

After a couple of hours of trying, I realized I that I should have added a position relative to the .hero-content and give it a z-index value that's greater than the #hero-section and #overlay.

Answer (score 0):

It works when you remove the definition of `position: relative` in `#hero-section` style.

```js
document.getElementById('button').addEventListener('click', function() {
  console.clear();
  console.log("Clicked!");
});
```

```css
#hero-section {
    /* background: url('../images/Hero\ section.jpg') center center/cover; */
    height: 90vh;
    /* position: relative; */
    z-index: -2;
}
#overlay {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  background: #000;
  opacity: 45%;
  z-index: -1;
}
.break {
  display: block;
}
.hero-content {
  padding-top: 18vh;
  text-align: center;
}
.hero-title {
  font-size: 60px;
  font-family: 'Playfair Display', sans-serif;
  color: #fff;
  margin-bottom: 2rem;
}
.btn-primary {
  background: #A841A1;
  color: #fff;
  border: none;
  padding: 1.25rem;
  font-size: 16px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<section id="hero-section">
    <div id="overlay"></div>
    <div class="hero-content">
        <h1 class="hero-title">Experience The Best Beauty
            <span class="break">Services</span>
        </h1>
        <button id="button" class="btn-primary">BOOK YOUR TREATMENT</button>
    </div>
</section>
```